# how to use stemDocument in R?

Tags: r, nlp

update:

Thanks for help. Check comments. Because of package version, I delete the tolower and it works. I just need to find another way to make it lower.

============
I am doing basic txt mining in with a list of document, everything goes on fine till I try to use `stemmDocument`.

the `tm_map` I already done is  as following with `library(tm)`

```
fbVec<-VectorSource(data[,1])
fbCorpus<-Corpus(fb.vec)
fbCorpus <- tm_map(fbCorpus, tolower)
fbCorpus <- tm_map(fbCorpus, removePunctuation)
fbCorpus <- tm_map(fbCorpus, removeNumbers)
fbCorpus <- tm_map(fbCorpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
fbCorpus <- tm_map(fbCorpus, removeWords, "pr")
fbCorpus <- tm_map(fbCorpus, stripWhitespace)
```

The results from it is as following

```
[[1]]
[1]  easy post position search resumes improvement searching resumes

[[2]]
[1]  easy use good candidiates improvement allow multiple emails sent 

[[3]]
[1]  applicants young kids absolutely sales experience waste time looking improvement applicants apply experience looking dont need kids just high school

[[4]]
[1]  abundance resumes
```

Then I tried to stem

```
library(SnowballC)    
fbCorpus <- tm_map(fbCorpus, stemDocument)
```

But the results is not as I image, it looks like only deal with the last word in a sentence, result as following:

```
[[1]]
[1]  easy post position search resumes improvement searching resum

[[2]]
[1]  easy use good candidiates improvement allow multiple emails sent 

[[3]]
[1]  applicants young kids absolutely sales experience waste time looking improvement applicants apply experience looking dont need kids just high school

[[4]]
[1]  abundance resum
```

Is there anyone can help?

Comment: I cannot replicate your result. Stemming with your data and code above works for me. What version of the `tm` and `SnowballC` library do you have installed? `sessionInfo() ` should tell you

Comment: @MrFlick [1] SnowballC_0.5    textcat_1.0-2    RTextTools_1.4.2 SparseM_1.03     tm_0.6           NLP_0.1-3 it is so strange....

Comment: I ran on tm 0.5.10. I helped someone before with tm 0.6 and it changed some things. I think the problem may be `tolower`. Can you try with out that?

Comment: @MrFlick Oh, yes! it is tolower! I delete it and it works! Don't know why.Thx! I suppose now I just need another way to make it all lower:)

Comment: I've posted a workaround as an answer. Hopefully that should work. (Not sure since i'm not running 0.6 so i can't test)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem appears in tm 0.6 and has to do with using functions that are not in the list of `getTransformation()` from tm. The problem is that `tolower` just returns a character vector, and not a "PlainTextDocument" like `tm_map` would like. The `tm` packages provides the `content_transformer` function to take care of managing the PlainTextDocument

```
fbCorpus  <- tm_map(fbCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not loading you document correctly. If you have your data in `x.csv` file then use following:

```
      > x <- read.csv(file_loc, header = TRUE) // where file_loc is the path to the csv file
      > x <- data.frame(lapply(x, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

     > require(tm)
         Loading required package: tm

     > dd <- Corpus(DataframeSource(x))

      > inspect(dd)
```

Then simply use `stemDocument` like below:

```
  fbCorpus <- tm_map(fbCorpus, stemDocument)
```

Comment: Please read my question,not just the title. I used this already, just it did not have a expected result.

Comment: Thx...but my code is exactly as your...and it did not work as well

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

If you look at the arguments for `stemDocuments` you can specify the language of stemming. I found by specifying "English" it solved the problem for me.

```
stemDocument(language="english")
```