# How can I identify words (say forest, forests) as one word either "Forest" or "Forests" in R using text mining package?

Tags: r, text-mining, word-frequency

I am trying to use R for text mining purposes using "tm" package. Please look at the frequency plot where it identifies Forest and Forests as two different words. How can I correct it i.e. I would prefer the total frequency count for Forests alone as a summation of both forest and forests. Thanks
[Frequency plot on R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlpIS.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R text mining - dealing with plurals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34938023/r-text-mining-dealing-with-plurals)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a stemming function of some sort. [`SnowballC`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SnowballC/index.html) provides this functionality (`wordStem` function).

It will reduce all words to their stem.

**Example**

```
stem(forests) = forest
stem(forest) = forest
```

Comment: I have already used Snowball c library(SnowballC)
> docs <- tm_map(docs, stemDocument)

Comment: If that does not work as expected, maybe have a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24311561/how-to-use-stemdocument-in-r