# How is the correct use of stemDocument?

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, stemming, snowball

I have already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24311561/how-to-use-stemdocument-in-r) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31438688/why-isnt-stemdocument-stemming) questions, but I still didn't understand the use of `stemDocument` in `tm_map`. Let's follow this example:

```
q17 <- VCorpus(VectorSource(x = c("poder", "pode")),
               readerControl = list(language = "pt",
                                    load = TRUE))
lapply(q17, content)
$`character(0)`
[1] "poder"

$`character(0)`
[1] "pode"
```

If I use:

```
> stemDocument("poder", language = "portuguese")
[1] "pod"
> stemDocument("pode", language = "portuguese")
[1] "pod"
```

it does work! But if I use:

```
> q17 <- tm_map(q17, FUN = stemDocument, language = "portuguese")
> lapply(q17, content)
$`character(0)`
[1] "poder"

$`character(0)`
[1] "pode"
```

it doesn't work. Why so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you stumbled on a bug. `stemDocument` works if you pass on the language when you do:

```
stemDocument(x = c("poder", "pode"), language = "pt")
[1] "pod" "pod"
```

But when using this in `tm_map`, the function starts of with `stemDocument.PlainTextDocument`. In this function the language of the corpus is checked against the language you supply in the function. This works correctly. But at the end of this function everything is passed on to the function `stemDocument.character`, but ***without the language component***. In `stemDocument.character` the default language is specified as English. So within the `tm_map` call (or the `DocumentTermMatrix`) the language you supply with it will revert back to English and the stemming doesn't work correctly.

A workaround could be using the package quanteda:

```
library(quanteda)
my_dfm <- dfm(x = c("poder", "pode"))
my_dfm <- dfm_wordstem(my_dfm, language = "pt")

my_dfm

Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents, 1 feature (0.0% sparse).
2 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dfm"
       features
docs    pod
  text1   1
  text2   1
```

Since you are working with Portuguese, I suggest using the packages quanteda, udpipe, or both. Both packages handle non-English languages a lot better than tm.

Comment: Tks @phiver! How can I get the word "pod" back to "pode" ou "poder" in my dfm with `quanteda`?

Comment: @GuilhermeParreira, you can't. You would need to use the `stemCompletion` function from tm. I never see the point in restemming, but then I never stem outside of English and even for English I find lemma's more useful. The lemma's and pos tagging are available in udpipe for Portuguese. You could use `stemCompletion` if you supply your own Portuguese dictionary. But read the documentation very carefully and check SO for some examples. It doesn't always behave as you expect. One of the reasons I tend to use other packages than tm.

Comment: My idea of using restemming is to make easier to the researcher to understand the analysis. Do you have any code which shows how to do it (starting from `quanteda` package?)

Comment: If dict is your dictionary with the words (`dict <-  c("poder", "pode")`), then you could use something like this:
`stemCompletion(tokens_wordstem(tokens(x = c("poder", "pode")), language = "pt"), dict, type = "first")`. This would result in pode turning into poder, because of the type selection. Read the help with stemCompletion which options there are. But for readability / understanding I would choose lemmatization.

Comment: Tks!! I managed to do what I wanted:
`dicionario <- featnames(my_dfm) # Original words`

`my_dfm <- dfm_wordstem(my_dfm, language = "pt")`
`radicais <- featnames(my_dfm) # Stemmed words`
`new.words <- as.character(stemCompletion(radicais, dictionary = dicionario)) # Fullfill the stem`
`my_dfm <- dfm_replace(my_dfm, radicais, new.words)  # Get back the words after stemming`