# stemDocument is not working well with tm_map function using a VCorpus

Tags: r, tm, stemming

When i transform in `R` my spanish text into a Corpus i can apply `stemDocument` in the `tm_map` function, though it returns me the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In tm_map.SimpleCorpus(col, stemDocument, "spanish") :
  transformation drops documents
```

I'm trying to do using VCorpus instead Corpus. It doesn't show me any warning message but the stemming doesn't wok as well.

```
col <- tm::VCorpus(VectorSource('patinetes eléctricos y bicicletas'))
col <- tm::tm_map(col, stemDocument, 'spanish')
col[[1]]$content

[1] "patinet eléctrico y bicicleta"
```

When i use `stemDocument('patinetes eléctricos y bicicletas', 'spanish')` the result is:

```
"patinet electr y biciclet"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is the correct use of stemDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54197636/how-is-the-correct-use-of-stemdocument)